# What's the intuition behind derivative of exponential function with non-exponential base?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Why does the derivative of $1.06^t$ = $1.06^tln(1.06)$?

My calc textbook gives the definition but I can't find an online explanation of why it holds.

Comment: Note $1.06^t=\exp(t\ln1.06)$

Answer (score 2):

Because the base of the function that satisfies $f'(x)=f(x)$ is $e$.  All other bases can be expressed by $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ and then the derivative follows by chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$y=1.06^t \implies \log(y)=t \log(1.06)\implies y=\exp\left(t \log(1.06) \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function of the form:

$$ f(x) = a^x$$

Then by definition of derivative:

$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{a^{x+h} - a^x }{h} = a^x \lim_{ h \to 0}  \frac{ a^h -1}{h}$$

We can write:

$$ a^h = e^{ h \ln a} = 1 + h \ln a + O(h^2)$$

Hence,

$$ f'(x) = a^x \ln a$$

---

Meta commentary:

We define $ e$ as the number for which $ \lim_{ h \to 0} \frac{e^h -1}{h} = 1$, this definition can be used to derive that $e^x$ is it's own derivatives. If we know the derivatives then we can derive it's series and once we do that we can make statements about other exponential statements by considering how the exponential grows in terms of $e^x$

Answer (score 0):

If we accept that $\frac {de^x}{dx} = e^x$.  And we accept that $\ln b = k\iff e^k = b$ (which is by definition) and if we assume $(b^r)^s = b^{rs}$ then......

$b = e^{\ln b}$ for all positive $b$.  (Note: $b$ is a constant value so $\ln b$ is a constant value.)

$b^x = (e^{\ln b})^x = e^{x\ln b}$

And so by the chain rule if  $y = x \ln b$  and $w = e^y = e^{x\ln b} = b^x$,  then $\frac {dw}{dx} = \frac {dw}{dy}\frac {dy}{dx}$.  And $\frac {de^y}{dy} = e^y$ and $\frac {d (x\ln b)}{dx} = \ln b$.

So $\frac {db^x}{dx} = \frac {e^{x\ln b}}{dx} = \frac {de^y}{dy}\frac {dy}{dx}= \frac {de^y}{dy}\frac {x\ln b}{dx} =$

$e^y\cdot \ln b = e^{x \ln b}\cdot \ln b= = b^x\cdot \ln b$.

...

Alternatively

$[b^x]' = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {b^{x+h} - b^x}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {b^x\cdot b^h + b^x}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0}(b^x\frac {b^h - 1}h)= b^x\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {b^h - 1}h$.

SO this boils down to .... why does $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {b^h-1}h = \ln b$?

Well..... note if $b = e$ we have $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {e^h-1}h = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {e^{\frac 1n} -1}{\frac 1n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}n(e^{\frac 1n} -1) =$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n([\lim_{m\to \infty}(1+\frac 1m)^m]^{\frac 1n} -1)=$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n([(1+ \frac 1n)^n]^{\frac 1n} -1)= $

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n(1+\frac 1n -1)=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\frac 1n=\lim_{n\to \infty} 1 = 1$.

For other $b$ ..... well,  tedious mechanism and spinning wheels but using definitions that $\ln x= Ln(x) := \int_1^x \frac 1tdt$ and $e^x = exp(x) = Ln^{-1}(x)$ and that $e;= exp(1)$ and that we can derive that $e = \lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n$ which would mean $e = \lim_{h\to 0^+}(1+h)^{\frac 1h}$ we can... with more headache  than I'm willing to endure, derive $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {b^h -1}h = \ln b$.

But we don't have to do that.  We can prove by first principals that $Ln(x)+Ln(y)=\int_1^x\frac 1t dt + \int_1^y\frac 1t dt =\int_1^{xy}\frac 1t dt=Ln(xy)$ and therefore $exp(a)exp(b) = exp(a+b)$ so $e^x =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {e^{x+h} -e^x}h =e^x$ and then our result follows by the chain rule.